# passing a pointer to member function to a parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, std

I have a class which derives from another class who implements a map of callback functions
I need to pass pointers to the callback from the child to the parent but i get compilation conversion errors
i'm trying to understand what is the correct way of doing this...

here are my classes

```
class handler
{
public:
    handler(){}
    using Callback = std::function<void(const string&, const string&)>;
    void AddTopicCallbackPair(const string& _st ,Callback _cb)
    {
        m_callbackDictionary.insert(std::make_pair(_st, _cb));
    }
private:
    std::map<const string&, Callback> m_callbackDictionary;
};
```

and i inherit this class by this class

```
class specificHandler : public handler
{
public:
    specificHandler()
    {
        AddTopicCallbackPair("/root/dev/", std::bind(callback1,this));
    }
    void callback1(const string& _topic, const string& _jsonData);
    void callback2(const string& _topic, const string& _jsonData);
    
private:
}
```

i thought about using something like this

```
class Handler 
{
.....
template <typename T>
using Callback = void(T::*)(const string&, const string&)
.....
}
```

and then in the specificHandler:

```
Callback f = &specificHandler::callback1;
AddTopicCallbackPair("/root/dev/", std::bind(callback1,this));
```

but it didn't work for me and i got compilation errors:

```
error: cannot convert 'void (specificHandler::*)(const string&, const string&)' {aka 'void (specificHandler::*)(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)'} to 'handler::CallbackFunc' {aka 'void (handler::*)(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)'} in initialization
   21 |     CallbackFunc f = &specificHandler::callback1;
```

Comment: `Callback` or `CallbackFunc`? Please try to show us a proper [mre] of the failing code.

Comment: [There is nothing wrong](https://godbolt.org/z/nsdY3a8Yq) with `Callback cb = std::bind(&Foo::callback1, this, _1, _2);` VTC as typo

Comment: The (optimized) lambda approach is already mentioned in an answer. I just point out `srd::bind_front(&callback1, this)` as the preference when you don't need reordering parameters and do not want place holders.

Answer (score 2):

Since `m_callbackDictionary` required a concrete type, having a template type aliases is not a good idea. In fact, you don't need it here.

I would suggest [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) over `std::bind` here:

```
class specificHandler : public handler
{
public:
    specificHandler()
    {
        AddTopicCallbackPair("/root/dev/", 
            [this](const std::string& _topic, const std::string& _jsonData) 
            { return this->callback1(_topic, _jsonData);  });
    }
    
    // ....code
};
```

[Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f8fEd8ajh)

Also, change the key type of `std::map` to a non-const-reference type in `handler` class.

Otherwise, it will make issues while instantiating the member functions of the `std::map`, where the function overloads, that takes `key_type` as forwarding references and a `const-&`.

```
class handler
{
public:
    using Callback = std::function<void(const std::string&, const std::string&)>;
    void AddTopicCallbackPair(std::string _st, Callback _cb)
    {
        m_callbackDictionary.emplace(std::move(_st), _cb);
        // construct in-place ^~~~~~~ using std::map::emplace
    }

private: 
    std::map<std::string, Callback> m_callbackDictionary;
    //       ^~~~~~~~~~~ non-const ref
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) requires [`std::placeholders::_1`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) when you need to call it with arguments.

So it would be

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
//...
std::bind(&Foo::callback1, this, _1, _2)
```

Your syntax would be for [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) (C++20)

```
std::bind_front(&Foo::callback1, this)
```

As  alternative, there is still lambda:

```
[this](const std::string& topic, const std::string& data){ this->Foo::callback1(topic, data); )
```